# Get childNode in childNode in XMLDocument

Tags: c#

I have XML response from service and I need to get value of tag that exist in child node that this child node is a child node.

For example: This is an example of xml.

```
<ashrait>
<response>
<command>inquire</command>
<inquire>
    <row>
        <ResponseCode>000</ResponseCode>
        <ResponseText>
        Permitted.
        </ResponseText>
        <ResponseXML>
            <ashrait>
            <response>
            <message>Permitted .</message>
            <userMessage>Permitted .</userMessage>
            </response>
            </ashrait>
        </ResponseXML>
    </row>
</inquire>
</response>
</ashrait>
```

I need the the value in tag "userMessage" that exists in tag "ResponseXML".

I know that to get the node of "ResponseXML" I need for those lines:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(responseFile);
ChildNode result = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ResponseXML")[0];
```

But how i get  the tag userMessage in childNode "ResponseXML"?

Thanks

*UPDATE:*

I figured out how to do it.
Search for all the children with the tag and choose the order they want.

Answer (score 0):

Use

- SelectNodes method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx
- or SelectSingleNode method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode(v=vs.110).aspx

  ```
      var doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml(Xml);
      XmlNode xn = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ashrait//inquire//row//ResponseXML//message");
      var innerText = xn.InnerText;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Create a model for your XML, load that model using `XmlSerializer`. 
Check this Microsoft Docs. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization